# CSS vertical-align:middle not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, vertical-alignment

I have the this piece of code here...

```
 <div class="pics2">

<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 4; opacity: 1; width: 225px; height: 200px;"> // this div is generated via jQuery Plugin
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height:200px;">
<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image5'] ?>" width="225" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS

```
.pics2 {  
    padding: 0;  
    margin-left:20px auto;
    margin-right:20px auto;
    width:225px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
        float:left;
}

.pics2 div{
    width:225px;
    height:200px;
}

.pics2 img {    
        background-color: #eee;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

What I am trying to do is vertically align the image inside three `div`s, the code above works in every single browser except IE7...any one got any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: That's because `display: table-cell` is not supported in IE7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope it will help to resolve your issue(Some cheats for IE 7 in the bottom of the article)

[Vertically Center Multi-Lined Text](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

For Example code like this

```
margin-top: expression((parentNode.offsetHeight.offsetHeight/2)-(parseInt(this.offsetHeight)/2) <0 ? "0" :(parentNode.offsetHeight/2)-(parseInt(this.offsetHeight)/2) +'px');
```

instead of

```
 vertical-align:middle;
```

1. `parentNode.offsetHeight/2` - determines the container's height and divide it by 2. This gives us a margin exactly half the height of the screen
2. `-(parseInt(offsetHeight)/2))` - determines the height of the centering block.

Comment: CSS expressions are very bad juju, just FYI.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the height of the div (you are specifying it at 200px), you can fix it like this:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
}
.v-middle{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pics2">

<div class="container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 4; opacity: 1; width: 225px; height: 200px;"> // this div is generated via jQuery Plugin
<div class="v-middle" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height:200px;">
<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image5'] ?>" width="225" />
</div>
</div>
```

Edit: Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/MUrbL/

Comment: this did not work, all it did was move my image to right and it cuts it off